# Configure jenkins with different build tupes

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have a question about configuring jenkins.

I have two build types in my build gradle file for my android project. Release and debug.

I want configure jenkins with option where I can choose what I want to build - release or debug.

I can't find any useful article how i can do this in my android application.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Why not just build both?

Comment: After I will add this, I want add build flavors for each build type. Testers need only debug application, with different flavors. And release app I should build only when we go to production =)

Comment: Then it seems you really want separate jenkins jobs for each.

Comment: @laalto maybe =) can you give me some link to read how i can configure it in different jobs?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple. I'm build my app using grade script

1. Add build parameter "Choice parameter" with any name(In my case name is "BUILD_TYPE")
2. Add choices, in my case they are "Debug" and "Release"
3. In section "Invoke gradle script", in "tasks" write this - "clean assemble$BUILD_TYPE"
4. Save changes

Done! Now you will choose debug or release, and Jenkins will provide you with different build types of your app